# Close hole after using screw modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, vertices, screw-modifier

I am trying to create a specific kind of look on a mesh, as to be seen on the following picture:

https://www.bz-berlin.de/data/uploads/multimedia/archive/00375/Merida2_375848a-724x432.jpg

Doesn't have to be 100% accurate, since it won't be too close in the final render, but I still want that swirl effect at the end parts of the bow.

In the picture you can see my attempt to screw two vertices, connected via an edge, to create a similar effect, but whatever I do I end up with a distorted spiral, or with a big hole in the middle. Any idea how I can close this hole? Or maybe a smarter way to get by?

Thanks already! :)

[image]

Comment: You can enable the Extra Curves Add-on and then add a spiral curve that can be used as Array Modifier length and Curve Modifier. The down-side is you will have to fiddle with the size of the spiral and the size of the plane. I tried it and got a lot of over lapping geometry but at least no hole in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a circle or with Grid Fill, but it really depends on your goal, what are you supposed to do with this spiral?

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I want the spiral to go on, without being interrupted as to be seen in your suggestions. I guess I will check out the suggested extra curves add-on and see what happens.